# Extract pixel values for multiple rasters to the same csv in R

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have multiple rasters scattered over a region and one shp with several polygons over some of the rasters.

[like this image, there are many others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guM5I.png)

I want to extract the median values of those polygons in each of the images to one same csv without losing the attribute values of the shp. I could do it one by one, but there has to be a way to automate it. I have tried to use a for loop, but the csv returned only had the values of 1 of the images of the list.

```
dir<-"C:/Users"
listImages <- lapply(list.files(dir, pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE), raster)
shp<-readOGR("shapefile.shp")

for(i in listImages) {
  imgextr<-extract(i, shp, fun=median, df=TRUE )
  write.csv(imgextr, file="test.csv") 
}
```

This is as far I could manage to go with the loop. I would really like to avoid creating one csv per raster, which are many. I have also attempted to use lapply, with no success:

```
extractor <- function(img){
imgextr<-extract(i, shp, fun=median, df=TRUE)
write.csv(imgextr, file = 'test.csv')))
 }
lapply(listImages, FUN=extractor)
```

Here the error I get is "Error in basename(a_csv) : a character vector argument expected "

Any help and explanation that will help me understand will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop was inevitable but I combine all resulting data frames into one.

```r
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

# List tif files
Files <- list.files(pattern = ".tif")

# Read shapefile with quadrats
uav <- readOGR("shapefile.shp")

# Name your output variable
# Raster Layer requires one value
# For RasterStack or Raster Brick, a value per layer
VAR = "median_ndvi"

# List collecting results of every run
DF <- list()

# Collecting information in a loop
for(i in Files) DF[[i]] <- {
        r <- raster(i)
        names(r) <- VAR # set a standard name for the layer
        imgext <- extract(x = r, y = uav, fun = median, df = TRUE)
        # Discard NA values
        imgext <- imgext[!is.na(imgext[ , VAR]),]
        imgext
}

# Since all data frames have the same columns
# you can call 'rbind()'
DF <- do.call(rbind, DF)
```

EDIT: Against a previous version, I simplified a bit more the answer. You name the output variable with `VAR`, while the `ID` corresponds to the row in the input `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? In my example I used the Amersfoort CRS ("+init=epsg:28992") with a 100x100 resolution. Make sure to change that to your crs and preferred value.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(exactextractr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)

calc_median <- function(){
  #list raster files
  listImages <- lapply(list.files(dir, pattern = ".nc$", full.names = TRUE), raster)

  #create a mask (defined resolution, same extend and crs as shapefile)
  RasterMask <- raster() #create raster
  extent(RasterMask) <- extent(shp) #set extent to extent of shapefile
  res(RasterMask) <- c(100, 100) #define resolution
  crs(RasterMask) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992") #set crs

  #create a list to bind results to
  result <- list() #create list
  
  #calculate median values using a for loop
  for(i in listImages){
    #read raster file
    rasterfile <- i
    
    #convert raster file to crs of rastermask
    rasterfile <- projectRaster(rasterfile, RasterMask, crs = crs(RasterMask))
    
    #extract median value for polygon
    poly_extract <- copy(shp) #copy shapefile
    poly_extract$Median <- exact_extract(rasterfile, poly_extract, 'median') #extract median value
    poly_extract$Raster <- names(rasterfile) #add name of raster file
    result[[names(i)]] <- poly_extract #add results to list
  }
  
  #rbind results, convert to data table in the process (for pivot_wider)
  result_bind <- setDT(do.call(rbind, result))
  
  #pivot_wider results (for overview)
  result_reordered <- pivot_wider(result_bind, names_from = Raster, values_from = Median)
  
  #return result
  return(result_reordered)
}

#run function. You can save it using fwrite if you want.
median_values <- calc_median()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I cannot make it work. I get " Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘exact_extract’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"’. I have changed the crs to 32632, and the res to 10x10. For more details, each image is 10x10 cm resolution, and the shapefile is a multipart polygon with 1490 records, and not all of them overlap with an image.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you convert your spatialpolygonsdataframe to an sf object (i think this can be done by running shp <- st_as_sf(shp) as the first line within the function.